# Python + Flask + Gunicorn + Nginx

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am new to web engineering but would like to create a RESTful API service in Flask, running on a Linux VM which can handle and respond to POST requests. I have seen the combination of Python + Flask + Gunicorn + Nginx. Is there an establish way to do this?

I have created a Flask app within a python script and created a .service file which points to this script.

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: I think every tutorial describes it in similar way - so maybe find some tutorial. Stackoverflow is a place where you show code and full error message and we try to resolve this single problem. Maybe your problem better fit to [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a library that might help you get off the ground. There are examples of complete apps in the `/examples` directory and lots of good info in the docs on how to set up an API.

https://github.com/dtiesling/flask-muck